# Call to undefined method when using $this

Tags: php, class, methods, this

I'm having some troubles using `$this`.

I have a Controller:

```
class UserController {
    public function show() {
        // prepare $array from database
        if ok
            return Response::toJson($array);
        else
            return Response::respondWithError("errorMessage");
    }
}
```

And the Response class:

```
class Response
{
    private function respond($array)
    {
        //do som
    }

    public function toJson($array)
    {
        // do som
        $this->respond($array);
    }

    public function respondWithError($message)
    {
        // do som
        $this->respond($array);
    }
}
```

And I get the error:

> Call to undefined method UserController::respond()

Why `$this` doesn't refer to Response class but UserController? And how can I call the `respond()` method from `foo()`?

Comment: You are calling `Response::foo` statically and then the `$this->respond();` is trying to access the method of an instance of `Response`.

Comment: So I have to return Response::respond() ?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're doing but you could `return self::respond();`

Comment: I edited the code. I'm trying to create a class that handle the json response, called from every controllers of the app.

So I want to give to the Response class the data (or the error) and let it internally manage and return in json.

I made two methods static and used self:: and it works. Just wondering if it's a good way.

Comment: Instead of dropping a lot of heavy programming words and terms - do you know what `$this` is and what `static` does to a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you use `$foo` as static, so declare it as static, and it is more clear...
You can't use `$this` on a static method...
you could make `respond()` static and then use `self::respond()`

Comment: I'm using your answer. Just wondering if it's the right way to achieve my goal.

Comment: If you don't want to do it this way, you'll have to make an object of class Response, and so you wouldn't need all static keywords

Answer (score 0):

You can't use methods inside a STATIC method, because that way you will broke the [encapsulation of OO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$this` in `foo`, you must define `respond` static too:

```
class UserController {
    public function show() {
        // do something
        return Response::foo($array);
    }
}
class Response {
    private static function respond() {
        // do something
    }

    public static function foo($array) {
        // do
        return self::respond();
    }
}
```